# Laravel 8 reading post with public friends private constraints

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js

can I ask you for further help? I'm having trouble implementing post reading by setting up public friends private links.
I have a bachecas table in which the posts are contained, with these columns id_post, content, privacy

[Bachecas table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9upU.png)

```
 privacy = 1 "public"
 privacy = 2 "friends"
 privacy = 3 "private"
```

then i have a user_follower table with following_id, follower_id, relationship tables

[User_follower table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSaM0.png)

relationship = 1 "fan"
relationship = 2 "friend"

and then the user table containing the data of the registered users.

What I would like to do is if there are following_id == 1 and follower_id == 2 and the relationship == 2 "friend"
id_post.privacy == 2 "friends" or id_post.privacy == 1 "public"
id2 can view messages from id1, while if id_post.privasy == 3 "private" the message can only be viewed by the current user.

With the following code I can visualize it correctly, but I would like to add the privacy constraint

```
        public function get (Request $request)
        {
    
        $posts =bacheca::join('users', function ($join) use ($current_id) {
            $join->on('users.id', '=', 'bachecas.id_utente')
            
    
            ->join('user_follower', function ($join2) use ($current_id) {
              $join2->on('bachecas.privacy', '=', 'user_follower.following_id')
                ->where('user_follower.stato', '=', 2)
                ->where('user_follower.follower_id', '=', $current_id)
                ->orOn('users.id', '!=', 'user_follower.following_id')
                ->where('users.id', '=', $current_id); 
               });       
        })
        ->orderBy('bachecas.created_at', 'desc')
        ->select('users.name', 'users.cognome', 'users.fotoProfilo','bachecas.contenuto_post')
        ->get();
    
      return response()->json($ posts);
      }
```

Can you please help me? Or if you have another better system, perhaps using a many-to-many relationship, thank you very much

Comment: privasy is "privacy"?

Comment: yes I wrote wrong :)

Comment: many-to-many is the best idea in your case.

Comment: ok, but would you have a practical example for my case? So can I get an idea? Thank you so much

Comment: No help friends?